# MyPy: How to type an argument that will forward to isinstance()

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I'm writing a predicate function. Among other things, it can take an argument that is compatible with `isinstance()`, such that if you called `my_pred(val, types)`, it would return `isinstance(val, types)`.

However, I'm not sure how to type that second argument correctly when defining my predicate. The second argument of `isinstance()` appears to be a MyPy-internal type named `_ClassInfo`. Is there a way to get access to that type? *Should* I try to get access to that? Or should I just give up and type it as `Any`?

(I can't write the type correctly manually, because it's recursive and MyPy doesn't yet support recursive types correctly; a `_ClassInfo` can be a `Type`, or a `tuple[_ClassInfo]`.)

Comment: Can't you use `Type | Collection[Type]`? (Or `tuple` instead of `Collection`)

Comment: @mkrieger1 that would be incorrect, it must be a `tuple`

Comment: No, as `tuple[tuple[Type]]` is a valid isinstance() arg, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, these stubs come from `typeshed`, here is a link to where [this is defined](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/c51de8ee6859b3b1b411d48e56cd537716893e81/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L1385), where currently you have:

```
if sys.version_info >= (3, 10):
    _ClassInfo: TypeAlias = type | types.UnionType | tuple[_ClassInfo, ...]
else:
    _ClassInfo: TypeAlias = type | tuple[_ClassInfo, ...]

def isinstance(__obj: object, __class_or_tuple: _ClassInfo) -> bool: ...
```

So it looks like it *is* using a recursive definition.*, which mypy has had some limited support for since v0.990/v0.991:

https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/13297

Although, it isn't perfect, but I guess it handles this case.

Comment: Perfect, that was a great help! Clearly I haven't double-checked for recursive types in the past year.